# Bootstrap Carousel - get images from database via php first image to be random then in order

Tags: php, html, carousel

I am using a bootstrap carousel to show images in a slideshow, I retrieve the images via PHP from my database, here is my code:

```
    <div class="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
           <?php

              $myConnection= mysqli_connect("$server","$username","$password") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
              mysqli_select_db($myConnection, $database) or die ("no database");  

              $queryy = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE type = 'topofpage' ";
              $sqll = mysqli_query($myConnection,$queryy);
              while ($img=mysqli_fetch_array($sqll)) {
              ?>
                <div class="item">
                   <img src="test/assets/img/top/<?php echo $img['filename']; ?>" class="center">
                </div>
             <?php
              }

             ?>
         </div>
   </div>
```

This works perfectly fine, and I don't have any issues, however I would like the first image to be selected as random and images to follow in order.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have two id="date" ?

Comment: @SenQiao to reference the id when doing insert command with php prepared statements.

Comment: Maybe having a <div> tag and a <input> tag with the same id will throw an error? Since id should be unique.

Comment: You cannot have multiple IDs. Also, for the purpose of form submission, form data uses the `name` field as keys. The only reason why you need ID for input elements is for the `<label for="...">` to work.

Comment: Thanks for the comments gents but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: We need the code for the actual call to the validator. One explanation would be that the validation happens before datepicker sets the date or that it happens on a keyup/down or something (since it works on normal input but using the picker breaks it means that either the value is empty on the trigger moment or something doesn't trigger). Unrelated with your problem, the guys are right id is unique and will generate you issues.

Comment: Thanks @zozo I have updated my answer with the url to the tuts i used.

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah I edited my answer with a workaround. Tested on their demo and works fine.

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah Cheers. The edits on your question make no sense... is a totally different question now... why not ask a new one? Now whoever reads this won't understand a thing from comments/answers. The original was a bout a field validation not triggering, now is about a random image order from php.

Comment: @zozo I asked a few stupid questions and lost the ability to ask another :( and so I had to edit an existing question to try gain the ability to retreive back my ability to ask a new question...

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah Editing old questions with a different question will most likely result in further issues. Ask on meta for your "right to ask" back.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the link you provided. There is no datepicker there so I presume you added it manually.

The problem is that the event is triggered on "input" event. Changing the value from js (like you are doing with the datepicker will not trigger the data change for validation). I tested that here: http://twitterbootstrap.org/live/bootstrap-form-validation/1/ using the email field (just updated it from console, reproduced the issue).

To trigger manually you can do this:

```
$('#date').trigger('input');
```

(Try it for console, and if it works you can figure a way to implement it in your setup)

Comment: Thanks for your response, that makes sense, I am new to JS and have no idea how i would implement/amend that with my already slightly altered code, please can you give me a head start?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by doing the following:

```
        <div class="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
           <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <?php

               $myConnection= mysqli_connect("$server","$username","$password") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
               mysqli_select_db($myConnection, $database) or die ("no database");  

               $queryy = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE type = 'topofpage' ";
               $sqll = mysqli_query($myConnection,$queryy);
               while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqll)) {
               /* Get the column in question and turn into array */
               $slimages[] = $row['filename'];
               /* Encode array */
               json_encode($slimages);
               }
               /* shuffle array to randomise */
               shuffle($slimages);
               $i = 0;
               foreach($slimages as $pimg)
               {
               ?>
                 <div class="item" data-slide-number="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                   <img src="test/assets/img/top/<?php echo $pimg; ?>">
                 </div>
               <?php   
                 $i++;
                }
               ?>
              </div>
        </div>
```

This then loops through the images retreived from the database and then iterates through them.

If page is refreshed the images are reshuffled, this approach in comparison to rand() means the same image won't show twice.